# insertRow() and appendChild() equivalent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use this code in React:

```
export const JsonToTable = (jsonArr) => {
var cols = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
    for (var key in jsonArr[i]) {
        if (cols.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            cols.push(key);
        }
    }
}

var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);             
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); 
    th.innerHTML = cols[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
}

 for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
     tr = table.insertRow(-1)
     for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
         var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
         tabCell.innerHTML = jsonArr[i][cols[j]];
     }
 }
 return table;
```

}

But React complains about these methods:

```
insertRow()
appendChild()
innerHTML
```

I know the equivalent of innerHTML is dangerouslySetInnerHTML but I don't want to use that.
If I run this code as is, I get the error that the object returned (table), is not a React type.
How can I write this function as a React component? 
What I'm trying to achieve is dynamically create a table from json. If there is another way to achieve that, I can look into that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the data you want to render in a table into the component's state.

When you want to change it, change the state.

The render function will automatically update the DOM.

For that matter, since it doesn't look like you are changing it internally … just pass the parsed JSON as a prop.

You can even use a function component.

```
const Table = ({ array }) => (<table><tbody>{array.map(generateRow)}</tbody></table>);
const generateRow = rowData => (<tr>{rowData.map(generateCell)}</tr>);
const generateCell = cellData => (<td>{cellData}</td>);
```